# Using xhost, display and startx - confused

Tags: centos, xorg, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a client A (192.168.1.1)(vncviewer) accessing Server B (192.168.2.1) (RHEL6) to run a installer.
The installation pre-requisite is to set the xhost and DISPLAY properly.

Q1) Please correct me if I am wrong for the following

- Xserver should be running in clientA
- DISPLAY should be set in Server B
- DISPLAY should be set to 192.168.1.1 (of client A's IP)
- Xhost on clientA should be set to allow Server B's IP (192.168.2.1)

Q2) Overhere, although I am running the installer over a network, I am using VNC to do it, and not using X.  Do I still need to set the xhost and DISPLAY parameters ? If not, what value should be provided respectively for these parameters ?

Q3) In terms of X11 forwarding, what are the configurations that should be done on client A and Server B ?

Hope to hear your advices soon.

Regards,
Noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vncviewer running on A talks (via the vnc protocol) to a vncserver (acting as an X server) or directly to the X server (with the vnc extension) running on B.

So really all the X protocol happens exclusively on B (even if they are displayed via vnc on A), so the `xhost` and `DISPLAY` ops (specific to the X protocol) done inside the terminals displayed in vncviewer apply directly to B.

Normally you shouldn't need `xhost` (or maybe add `localhost` if needed).

Normally `DISPLAY` should already be set to the `:N` corresponding to the `vncserver` running on B.

Comment: Thanks Dan. When we connect via VNC to B, does the VNC protocol talk to any X protocol specifically in B.   I just thought that connecting via VNC is ike connecting to the console of B over the network and running any program doesn't need X at all.   When we run a program locally in Server B on site at the console, do we need to set any parameters ?

Comment: VNC communication is not X, only the at the B endpoint the server behaves like an X server for the apps running locally on B and displayed in the VNC session. What you thought is VNC is actually terminal/text ssh or telnet. When on B's console in graphics mode you're running under the local X server (xhost and DISPLAY apply, but normally they're already set on most/all modern linuxes).

Comment: in normal x remote connection -> the user accessing the app is running the X server and the server running the app is the X client - right ?  Putting vnc and ssh aside, if i am accessing the server B physically via its console, is X being use to display graphic on the monitor ? If yes, does it means that Server B is both the X server and the client ?

Comment: Yes(the app is the client). Yes. Yes.

Comment: in that case if i am using VNC to make a remote connection to Server B , can i say Server B is both the X server and the X client as well ? We are viewing the display over VNC. But the display is send locally from the client to the server (both in ServerB) - am i right ?

Comment: Yes, with a tiny note - the client can also be a remote app running elsewhere and showing on that display (possible if, for example, your installation script running on B also executes stuff on other servers)

Comment: you mean B is running some app elsewhere and with relate to that, B is the X server, and the app elsewhere is the X client.  Then with me, viewing the GUI on B from VNC.  Right ?

Comment: Yes to the 1st statement. The VNC example is only similar in functionality, but it's using VNC, not X, so technically it's not the same.

Comment: Thanks a million.  Do you know what the parameter value to have the DISPLAY point to a X server locally  ? is it DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 ? do i need to have localhost in the hostfile ?

Comment: Depends - multiple X servers may be running, vncserver processes have their own, etc. If you are already connected to/viewing the server (and you didn't mess with the DISPLAY var in your .rc files) it's typically set automatically: open a new terminal and `echo $DISPLAY` in it.

Comment: You mentioned "vncserver processes have their own", what do you actually meant by that ?  what is the relationship here between VNC and X server over here.  Is vnc server process on B sending API requests to B's X server ?